# How to resolve "the current .NET SDK does not supporting targeting .NET Core 2.2"

Tags: .net-core, sdk, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.2

So I get the error in the title when I'm working with a project I know has been created using core 2.2. However, I've looked into this and done the following things which I've found can be potential problems:

1. Updated visual studio (2017) to the latest version.
2. Obviously I've installed the 2.2 SDK (tried both 64 and 32 bit versions). When I run dotnet --version in PowerShell I'm shown that my current version is 2.2.202
3. Activated "use previews of the .NET Core SDK" under tools->options->projects and solutions-> .NET Core, although this shouldn't be necessary since it's not a preview anymore...

When I right click a project and go to properties I'm unable to select .net core 2.2 under target framework. I've obviously tried restarting VS.

So far I've been unable to find any other possible causes. Do anyone have any idea what else I could possibly be missing?

Comment: do you have a global.json in that folder or in a parent folder (anywhere in the directory hierarchy)? also: go to a command-prompt **in that folder**, and use `dotnet --version` - what does it say?

Comment: additional: if you use `dotnet --info`, **where** does it say 2.2 is installed? is it under program files? or under your user profile? Finally: **make sure you use the command prompt for this** - I've seen cases where powershell and command-prompt *disagree on paths* on the same machine - and things that work in powershell do not work in the command-prompt (this usually happens if you use powershell to install the SDK); Visual Studio works like the command-prompt, not like powershell

Comment: @MarcGravell If I do dotnet --info in that folder using cmd it still says 2.2.202. There's no global json in the folder, though, but I have tried creating one and it makes no difference. But the dotnet command in that folder does say it's "reflecting any global.json".

Comment: I assume it works with `dotnet build`? is updating to VS2019 an option? https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: @MarcGravell Yep, `dotnet build` through cmd in the folder works. So there's something about visual studio not registering that it should have 2.2 available. I'd like to fix it without going to 2019, since other people in the project work with 2017.

Comment: I just tested uninstalling both x64 and x86. I then instally only x86, which does not register with dotnet --version/info. If I uninstall x86 and install x64 then that will be reflected in dotnet --version/info. But neither work with visual studio. I don't know if this information is any useful. Obviously I'm restarting visual studio as I'm testing these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has messed up the latest version on 2.2
It only works with visual studio/ msbuild 2019 now.

Spent a good hour figuring this out, but uninstall 2.2.202 and install an older version and it will work fine!

Comment: Did you find an announcement / post about this issue?  I was able to get around this by installing 2.2.105.

Comment: No announcement just noticed it broke for me today and they updated it yesterday. Then noticed a bunch of stack overflow posts from today with the same issue

Comment: Probably someone should put in a bug to Microsoft

Comment: I ended up going with VS 2019 after all. But I'll assume this is correct and accept it, I suppose.

Comment: @ghostbust555 Ok, this seems pretty sad but I also had to install vs2019 to get it working, spent an hour or so lurking for other solutions in the web